# Python Loop Through Dict

Tags: python

I've got some Python code and I'd like to apply different actions based on a column in a dict.

```py
try:
    columns = get_table_columns(table, cursor)
    print(columns)
```

In this columns dict, I've got

```py
{'EFF_DT': 'DATE', 'TERM_DT': 'DATE', 'PACKAGE_LABEL': 'TEXT'}
```

What I'd like to do is loop through that and go if it's date, apply one piece of logic (placing to_date around the field in SQL), and otherwise, just work normally.

This is my full code for this piece of the script

```py
for key in primary_keys:
        sql += '{table}."{key}" = {temp_table}."{key}"'.format(
            table=table, temp_table=temp_table, key=key
        )
        if key == primary_keys[-1]:
            continue
        sql += " and "

    sql += " WHEN MATCHED THEN  update set "

    for column in columns:
        if columns[column]=="DATE":
            sql+="{table}.\"{column}\" = TO_DATE({temp_table}.\"{column}\", 'DD/MM/YYYY'), ".format(table=table, temp_table=temp_table, column=column)
            continue
        sql+= "{table}.\"{column}\" = {temp_table}.\"{column}\", ".format(table=table, temp_table=temp_table, column=column)
    sql = sql[:-2]
    sql+= " when not matched then insert values ( "

    for column in columns:
        if columns[column]=="DATE":
            sql+="TO_DATE("+table+"_TEMP.\""+column+"\", 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
        else:
            sql+= table+"_TEMP.\""+column+"\""
        if column ==list(columns.keys())[-1]:
            sql += " );"
            continue
        sql+=", "
```

What I'm trying to do is add in a part into the `for key in primary keys` part where I check if the column is date and do the similar to the columns part but if I put in two for loops, it loops too much and it throws the sql code.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't that what you're already doing in your second `for` loop with the `if`/`else`?

Comment: Ya, so as I'm very new to Python (and my brain is fried), I didn't pick up what the second was doing fully, so I've fixed it now

Comment: No problem.  Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: Yup, think i spent so long looking at it, it started to turn into japanese for me

Comment: Sou desu ne?  Omoshiroi ...

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone else sees this in future,

this is what got it to work for me. Just asked a colleague and they saw the issue immediately.

All I needed to do was add in if columns[key] == "DATE": part to the for key in primary_keys section.

As the dict was already defined, I could query that

```
for key in primary_keys:
            if columns[key] == "DATE":
                sql += "{table}.\"{key}\" = TO_DATE({temp_table}.\"{key}\", 'DD/MM/YYYY') ".format(
                    table=table, temp_table=temp_table, key=key
                )
            else:
                sql += '{table}."{key}" = {temp_table}."{key}"'.format(
                table=table, temp_table=temp_table, key=key
                )
            if key == primary_keys[-1]:
                continue
            sql += " and "
        sql += " WHEN MATCHED THEN  update set "
```